Telegram server says - Bad Request: message can't be deleted for everyone
handler:
@router.callback_query(F.data == "remain_free_subscription")
async def remain_free_subscription_handler(
    query: CallbackQuery,
    bot: Bot,
    event_chat: Chat,
    user_service: FromDishka[UserService],
    settings_service: FromDishka[SettingsService],
    email_service: FromDishka[EmailService],
    audio_service: FromDishka[AudioService],
) -> None:
    await bot.delete_message(chat_id=event_chat.id, message_id=query.message.message_id)

    #<--some not essential logic right here-->

    await bot.send_message(chat_id=event_chat.id, text="Вы успешно переключились на подписку 'FREE'!")

Пытаюсь нажать на кнопку, но по итогу выскакивает ошибка, согласно которой message can't be deleted for everyone. Возможно она возникает из за того, что сообщение слишком старое и там с коллбэком чет не то и апдейт какой то не такой приходит, ибо сегодня у меня 9 августа, а сообщение, с которым я пытаюсь взаимодействовать было отправлено ботом 5 августа. Раньше все работало, но я нажимал на кнопку сразу и все успешно удалялось, а сейчас по истечению какого то промежутка времени ничего не воркает.
UPD: В общем я чекнул метод deete_message у aiogram и там в комментариях к нему написано A message can only be deleted if it was sent less than 48 hours ago.. Видимо как раз из за этого и возникает данная ошибка, что я пытаюсь удалить сообщение, которое было отправлено больше чем 48 часов назад.
Full error:
TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: message can't be deleted for everyone
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 309, in _process_update
    response = await self.feed_update(bot, update, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 158, in feed_update
    response = await self.update.wrap_outer_middleware(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\error.py", line 25, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\middlewares\user_context.py", line 49, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\fsm\middleware.py", line 42, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\dishka\integrations\aiogram.py", line 46, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 276, in _listen_update
    return await self.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 142, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\dishka\integrations\aiogram.py", line 46, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 137, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 170, in _propagate_event
    response = await router.propagate_event(update_type=update_type, event=event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 142, in propagate_event
    return await observer.wrap_outer_middleware(_wrapped, event=event, data=kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 137, in _wrapped
    return await self._propagate_event(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\router.py", line 162, in _propagate_event
    response = await observer.trigger(event, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\telegram.py", line 121, in trigger
    return await wrapped_inner(event, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\shrink\app\bot\middlewares\scheduler.py", line 20, in __call__      
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\shrink\app\bot\middlewares\subscription_middleware.py", line 38, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\dishka\integrations\aiogram.py", line 66, in __call__
    return await handler(event, data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\event\handler.py", line 43, in call
    return await wrapped()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\dishka\integrations\base.py", line 154, in autoinjected_func
    return await func(*args, **kwargs, **solved)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\shrink\app\bot\callbacks\subscription_system_calls.py", line 37, in remain_free_subscription_handler
    await bot.delete_message(chat_id=event_chat.id, message_id=query.message.message_id)
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\bot.py", line 1206, in delete_message
    return await self(call, request_timeout=request_timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\bot.py", line 482, in __call__
    return await self.session(self, method, timeout=request_timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\session\base.py", line 254, in __call__
    return cast(TelegramType, await middleware(bot, method))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\session\aiohttp.py", line 189, in make_request
    response = self.check_response(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python_all_projects\Ordered TG Bots\Shrink2\.venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\session\base.py", line 120, in check_response
    raise TelegramBadRequest(method=method, message=description)
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest: Telegram server says - Bad Request: message can't be deleted for everyone

